# Installing perforce visual client on linux

Tags: linux, perforce

I am from Mac background trying my hand at installing perforce client visual(P4V) on my linux box.For this I download the correct version  [here](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list) and untar the files.
 Then I cd to the directory

> ~/Desktop/p4v-2012-blah-blah/bin

I also say

> chmod +x p4*

After this i try running p4v (by double clicking) but I dont see anything .The file type is shown as a **"text executable"** but i dont know why it is not running.
On mac i had done the same thing -just clicked on p4v and the client would show up(where I filled the server address and everything )But not sure what is going wrong here.Can someone give me directions?

FWIW i did check out [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/01_install.html#1070774) link 
and I do see the desktop (so GNOME is probably installed ?) .Hence p4v should be able to run.

Comment: Try running it from the command line and see if there are errors.

Comment: How did you download it?  If you used ftp did you set binary mode?

Answer (score 1):

I know we don't like link-based answers, but there is a rather complete walk-through here: http://www.perforce.com/documentation/tenminute-test-drive-linuxunix

Probably should be on Super User though.

Comment: Link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 1):

You may have a 64bit Linux and tried to install a x86 P4V or vice versa, which is why the command doesn't run.  Check that the OS and app types match.